# Could not retrieve even a single tweet with latitude and longitude in R

Tags: r, twitter, leaflet

I tried running the below code (R Script) now. I could not retrieve even a single tweet with long/lat pair. I'm getting the text column. But, the lat/long pair for all the tweets retrieved shows NA (even for a generic search term like "twitter"). When I ran the same code before 5 months, I was able to retrieve tweets with lat/long pair. I guess the problem is with the Twitter Search API. I do not know how to sort this problem out.

(Ran the code with the API credentials)

/app.R

```
library(leaflet)
library(twitteR)

  consumerKey <- ""
  consumerSecret <- ""    
  accessToken <- ""
  accessSecret <- ""


    setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = consumerKey, consumer_secret = consumerSecret,access_token = accessToken, access_secret = accessSecret)

    mapTweets <- searchTwitteR("donaldtrump", 
                               n = 500, 
                               lang = "en", 
                               geocode = "37,-122,100mi")

    mapTweets.df <- twListToDF(mapTweets)

    mapTweets.df <- mapTweets.df[!is.na(mapTweets.df$longitude), ]


    rendermap <- leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = mapTweets.df, lng = mapTweets.df$longitude, lat = mapTweets.df$latitude, popup = mapTweets.df$screenName) %>%
      setView(lng = 37, lat = -122, zoom = 4)

    rendermap
```

Comment: Could you reduce this to the error you face when **just** using `searchTwitteR`? We're not going to diagnose your entire app.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll I've edited. Please check the code now!

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Even if I ask for 500 tweets, its returning all the tweets with lat/long as NA.

Answer (score 0):

The default twitter clients don't include specific lat/longs for most users.  Your search is broad enough that you are getting content related to users in an area or tagged with an entire city.

e.g. compare

```
$ tweetsearch geocode:37,-122,100mi | jq -r '.statuses[] | select(.place) | [.place.name, .coordinates?.coordinates] | flatten | @tsv'
Turlock
Novato
Burbank
Oakland
San Francisco
Oakland
Fresno
San Mateo
Alameda
San Bruno
Hayward
San Jose
Ceres
Fresno
San Jose
San Jose
Discovery Bay
Hayward
Modesto
Berkeley
San Jose
Antioch
San Lorenzo
San Jose
Alameda
```

And

```
$ tweetsearch geocode:37.781157,-122.398720,1mi | jq -r '.statuses[] | select(.place) | [.place.name, .coordinates?.coordinates] | flatten | @tsv'
San Francisco   -122.38977533   37.77854483
San Francisco   -122.38977533   37.77854483
San Francisco   -122.38977533   37.77854483
Mission Bay
San Francisco   -122.38977533   37.77854483
San Francisco   -122.38977533   37.77854483
San Francisco   -122.38977533   37.77854483
San Francisco   -122.4192647    37.7792597
South of Market
San Francisco   -122.418    37.775
San Francisco   -122.4192647    37.7792597
San Francisco   -122.41487603   37.78678264
San Francisco   -122.41487603   37.78678264
San Francisco   -122.418    37.775
South Beach
San Francisco   -122.41640337   37.78025867
San Francisco   -122.39832343   37.77958373
```

Comment: I understand! But I could not get the geocode using this R language.

Comment: Even when you narrow the search down?

Comment: Yes! I changed the radius from 500 mi to 5 mi. Even then, its not turning up